# When editing an answer to a question, how can one still view the question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've noticed when I'm editing an answer to a question that one no longer can see the question itself. Often I find myself wanting to cut and paste multiple blocks of text from the question in order to revise my answer. Because often its multiple blocks, copy/paste isn't the answer.

Maybe there is a modal dialog/toggleable view somewhere that I'm not seeing that contains the question? If not, could this be added as a feature request?

Comment: No repro...whenever I hit "answer" or "edit" it always takes me to an inlined editing box, leaving the page unchanged. JavaScript turned off?

Comment: @timpeterson All I have to do is scroll up. What are you seeing?

Comment: Still the same, it takes me to an inlined editing box, not changing the site. Do you have JavaScript turned off?

Comment: @Kobobby, vcsjones ok, sorry about this i didn't notice that there is resizeable bar that when dragged down can unveil the question. Should I answer the question with a picture showing the resizeable bar? I keep getting slammed on meta-SO so not sure what the etiquette is.

Comment: [How do I participate in Meta Stack Overflow and not die trying?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No can do. Just drag the bar and here is your question

[image]